# how do i call a method from another controller node

Tags: javascript, node.js

I have 2 models and 2 controllers.

UserModel.js, UserNameModel.js, and userController.js, userNameController.js

After I successfully register a user, I want to record & store that new username. the goal is to not reuse an already-used username

How do I design this function without calling a controller in the other controller,

```
userController.js 
    const register = async (req, res) => {
      const { userName, email } = req.body
      const newUser = await createNewUser(name, email)
    res.status(StatusCodes.OK).json({ newUser })
    }

userNameController.js 
     ......
```

Comment: What does this have to do with Ruby on Rails??

Answer (score 1):

The `module.exports` is a special object which is included in every JavaScript file in the Node.js application by default. The `module` is a variable that represents the current module, and `exports` is an object that will be exposed as a module. So, whatever you assign to `module.exports` will be exposed as a module.

so, you can use the separator file to write all functions you need for each model like users, contacts, and messages....

```
users.js

module.exports.createNewUser = async (data) => {
    write your code here.
    return user;
};

module.exports.checkUserExist = async (email) => {
    write your code here.
    return user;
};

module.exports.deleteUser = async (userId) => {
    write your code here.
    return true;
};
```

and if you want to use the file on any controller, should call it like.

```
userController.js

const {createNewUser, checkUserExist, deleteUser} = require(../users.js);

router.get('create-user', async (req, res) => {

    const newUser = await createNewUser(req.body);

    res.status(200).json({ newUser });
}
```